# Mysql database design issue

Tags: mysql, database

I know I am doing this wrong, so I'm hoping somebody here can help.  This is a little complicated, so I will try to explain this as best as I can.

I have a table of products with an id and a title.  A product can have many certificates and a certificate can have many products.  So far, these are my tables:

products
certificates
product_x_certificate

Here's the problem.  I need to also be able to offer products together.  So let's say I have these products:

towels
clubs
hats
balls

On one certificate, I offer towels with clubs.  On another certificate, I offer towels with hats, and yet on another, I offer hats with balls.  To make it even more complicated, customers have choices for each certificate.  So one certificate can have multiple offerings.  For instance, customers have the choice between balls and hats or towels and clubs on certificate A.

I tried creating a table called product_x_product and the fields are a_id, b_id, certificate_id, but I am running into all sorts of problems trying to display what product is offered with what product.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: From the answers that I have received so far, I see that I forgot to mention that I only have a certain number of certificates, so my certificates table is really a lookup table.  Basically, our customers have the ability to "build" or choose what they want on their certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have most of the tables that you need. In *Product_x_Certificate* you can have multiple certificate IDs and multiple product IDs which means you can have a set up like this:

```
Product_x_Certificate table
CertificateID - ProductID
45                  4
45                  7
46                  8
46                  9
47                  10
```

This way you have one or many products per certificate which satisfies your first requirement. As for the same certificate having multiple groups of products - why not just make a new certificate ID? Then if you need to conceptually group them you could make CertificateGroup and Certificate_x_CertificateGroup tables such that:

```
CertificateGroup table
CertificateGroupID     Name
1                       Hitting things

Certificate_x_CertificateGroup table
CertificateGroupID     CertificateID
1                         46
1                         47
```

Does this help?

Comment: I came up with a solution that was very close to yours, so I am giving you the credit since your answer got me thinking about the problem.  Basically, I'm going to change the name of the product_x_product table to product_groups.  It will have 4 fields: prod_group_id(primary), (cert_id, group_num, product_id)(unique).  I won't need a separate group table, I'll just create an arbitrary group number for the different products in the group associated with a certain certificate.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try something like,

prod_group(**group_id**, product_id references products (product_id))
group_certificate(**group_id**, cert_id references certificates (cert_id))

you can't really remove all of the redundancies

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your hierarchy should be:

- A certificate has one or more options.
- An option has one or more products.

To that end, the following schema is a good start:

```
certificates:
    certificateId   primary key
options:
    optionId        primary key
products:
    productId       primary key
    productName
optionProducts:
    optionId        references options(optionId)
    productId       references products(productId)
certificateOptions:
    certificateId   references certificates(certificateId)
    optionId        references options(optionId)
```

The `certificateOptions` table gives you the ability to have any number of options on a single certificate.

The `optionProducts` table allows any number of products for a given option.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure I fully understand the problem description, since I don't know why you can't create new certificates for different choices. But you seem to have three different objects which are quite arbitrarily related to each other, so it would seem to be convenient to create a table linking all three of them. So my proposed tables would be:

- products
- certificates
- choices
- product x certificate x choice

So in the last table you could add a given product to a certain certificate/choice combination. Since the certificate/choice combination defines a unique object, you could also create a `certificates&choices` reference table which would hold all this objects, and then you could create the relationship table `product x ...` which would assign the product to the combination.